# Why does work done by light not equal energy absorbed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electromagnetic-radiation

> Question: Suppose a spherical particle of mass $m$ and radius $R$ in space absorbs light of intensity $I$ for time $t$. (a) How much work does the radiation pressure do to accelerate the particle from rest in the given time it absorbs the light? (b) How much energy carried by the electromagnetic waves is absorbed by the particle over this time based on the radiant energy incident on the particle?

Why does the work done by the radiation pressure not equal the energy absorbed by the particle? Where does the extra work go?

Answer (score 1):

The radiation force is given by
$$F_r = \pi r^2 \frac{I}{c},$$
assuming that your $I$ is actually the magnitude of the Poynting vector in units of power per unit area.

This will accelerate the particle (uniformly, as long as the speed is $\ll c$ *
) so that it's velocity at time $t$ is
$$ v = \pi r^2 \frac{I}{mc}t$$
in the direction in which the force acts.

The work done is then
$$W = \int \vec{F}\cdot \vec{v}\ dt = \int Fv\ dt = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2m}\left(\pi r^2 \frac{It}{c}\right)^2$$

The amount of energy absorbed in time $t$ is just 
$$E = \pi r^2 I t\ .$$

The ratio of work done to energy absorbed is
$$\frac{W}{E} = \frac{\pi r^2 I t}{2mc^2} = \frac{v}{2c}$$
which is only valid for $v \ll c$ and  so this ratio is extremely small.

Where does the rest of the energy go? Either in making the particle hotter or ultimately it is radiated away in all directions by the particle. A perfectly absorbing particle in thermal equilibrium would be a blackbody radiator such that
$$\pi r^2 I = 4\pi r^2 \sigma T^4$$

Physically you can imagine the scenario in terms of the particle inelastically absorbing massless particles (photons) with momentum $p$ and speed $c$. Each absorbed photon contributes $pc$ of energy and increases the particle momentum, p_0, by $p$, its speed by $p/m$ and it's kinetic energy by $[(p_0+p)^2 -p^2]/2m \sim p_0p/m$. The ratio of added kinetic energy to absorbed energy is therefore $p_0/mc$. The reason for the missing factor of two is that $p_0$ is the current particle momentum, and the average efficiency is a factor of two lower when integrated from rest.

- If relativistic velocities are considered then you have to modify $I$ for the "Doppler diminishing" that would be seen in the particle frame of reference.

Answer (score 0):

The particle absorbs most of the energy as heat. That's where it goes.